# How to batch read set of documents in Firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I could not find any firestore batch read API where i can pass a set of docIds and i can fetch the docs in one network operation.

I dont want to make multiple network hops for each doc.

Any pointers will be helpful. Am trying to do this for android.

Comment: If you're using one of the mobile client APIs, you will have to make multiple API calls.  The queries are pipelined over a single connection, so there is not that much of a performance hit.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do i need to use a transaction in order to avoid round trips or will it use the same connection even in case if i dont use a transaction?

Comment: There is only ever one connection per client app actively running.